# MvvmCross Bitmap binding in Android

Tags: android, bitmap, imageview, mvvmcross

**Situation:** I’m using a web service to get the byte[] of an image and then store them in my local database.
My view model knows when to call the web service and save them to the local database. During this process the view model will update My Image of the `byte[]`. This process does it's job. But there is a problem in updating My Image on screen. The problem occurs only if I don't change the screen. Scroll-up and down or go back to page solves it. If the `byte[]` already in localdatabase theres no problem.

**Screen: Listitem**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     xmlns:local="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
     android:background="@android:color/white"
     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:orientation="vertical">    
     <Mvx.MvxImageView android:id="@+id/ImageViewNewsListItemNews"
              android:layout_width="70dp"
              android:layout_height="70dp"
              local:MvxBind="Bitmap MyImage,Converter=InMemoryImage”/>
</LinearLayout>
```

**Convertor:**

```
public class InMemoryImageConverter : MvxValueConverter<byte[],Bitmap>
{
  protected override Bitmap Convert(byte[] value, Type targetType, object parameter,CultureInfo culture)
    {
         if(value == null || value.length == 0){return null;}
         return BitmapFactory.DecodeByteArray(value, 0, value.Length);
    }

    protected override byte[] ConvertBack(Bitmap value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
     {
        var stream = new MemoryStream();
        value.Compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.Jpeg, 100, stream);
        return stream.ToArray();
     }
}
```

Comment: What is `MyImage` in the ViewModel?

Comment: Sorry - really need more info than that in order to help - how is `MyImage` signalled as changed? what thread is it signalled on? is the value converter called during the changed singal? etc Maybe consider editing the question rather than commenting - that'll make it easier to add code.

Comment: After the image is downloaded from the web I only set the MyImage its value by MyImage =Image. I dont call the Convertor again ( do not know how)

Answer (score 1):

You must add new packages : **MvvmCross.HotTuna.Plugin.PictureChooser**

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you don't have your MyImage property set up properly in your ViewModel.  I would expect that your MyImage property looks like this:

```
private byte[] myImage;
public byte[] MyImage
{
    get
    {
        return myImage;
    }
    set
    {
        myImage = value;
        RaisePropertyChanged(() => MyImage):
    }
}
```

The binding is not going to work unless you tell the UI it has changed.

Comment: Yes i  got the same setup. Maybe i must always set the value the first time by myImage=new byte[128]. How can i force to update the UI

Comment: If your binding is set up properly RaisePropertyChanged is what tells the UI to update.  In the above setup when you do MyImage = newImage RaisePropertyChanged event is called.  I think you need to add some more code on how you are downloading the image.  Perhaps you are not updating the view model property correctly?

Answer (score 0):

Here is some more code I use. In the viewmodel i got three functions: GetImageOfWebservice, CheckImageIsLoaded and OndownloadComplete(CallBack function). For downloading the image I use a object.

### Object(for downloading):

```
public class ImageOfWeb()
{
   public event OnDownloadComplete;
   public byte[] ImageArray;
   public long ImageID;
   public ImageOfWeb(Action<byte[]> Callback)
  {
    OnDownloadComplete +=Callback;
  }

  Public void DownloadImage()
  {
    var service = httpclient // etc... use webservice machnisme of vs here put i the imageID
    service.GetImageComplete +=(sender,args) =>
    {

       if(args != null && args.error == null)
       {
           ImageArray = args.response;

       } 
       else
       { 
         ImageArray = null;
       }

       if(OnDownloadComplete !=null)
       {
          OnDownloadComplete (ImageArray);
       }
       else
       {
        throw exeption("No Callback");
       }
    }
  }
}
```

### Functions Viewmodel

```
void GetImageOfWebservice ()
{
  var web = new ImageOfweb(OnDownloadComplete) {ImageID = MyImageID;}
  try
  {
   web.DownloadImage();
  }
  catch(exception e)
  {
   ShowTrace(e); // gives back exeception in mvx.trace
  }
}
void OnDownloadComplete(byte[] image)
{
  if(image == null || image.length ==0)
  {
    ShowTrace(string.format("{0} not downloaded",MyImageID));
  }
  else
  { 
    MyImage= image
   }
}
private byte[] myImage;
public byte[] MyImage
{
  get
  {
    return myImage;
  }
  set
  {
    myImage = value;
    RaisePropertyChanged(() => MyImage); CheckImageIsLoaded();
   }
 }
void CheckImageIsLoaded()
{
  if(MyImageId !=0 && (MyImage == null || MyImage.length == 0))
  {
     GetImageOfWebservice();
  }
 }
```

Note : I'm using MVVMCross of 19-april-2013.

Comment: Even the newest version got this problem